# Don’t install the LMA in the Developer Edition org where you created a managed package

Tags: partner-communities, lma

I have developed and uploaded `managed package` from my `developer edition org`. I have created listing in my `partner account`. I have set the price etc.  To link my app in `LMA` I am following this link [Install the License Management App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_install_app.htm) it says

**Don’t install the LMA in the Developer Edition org where you created a managed package.**

Where I am suppose to install?

Answer (score 4):

Install the LMA in your production org. This is necessary because the LMA will create leads for you as your clients install or try out your app. If you put this in your developer org, you may run out of storage space or might even accidentally create a dependency in your app on the LMA, which means your package could no longer be installed by clients.

Comment: I have developed my app on [this url](https://login.salesforce.com) which I suppose is `production org` and  `developer edition`. I don't  have any other.

Comment: @ozil As a partner, you should have a partner org that you log in to do your business. It is normally a Professional Edition or Enterprise Edition (or whatever else you chose to use). It will not be a Developer Edition.

Comment: I suppose only `Developer Edition.` is free?

Comment: @ozil Yes, DE orgs are free.

Comment: @sfdcfox Do you mean the Partner Business Org or a regular Production Org?  Asking in reference to my post [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275495/lma-install-on-partner-business-org-or-our-production-org)